# How to run function that in packages in oracle (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I need to call to some function  and procedures that in packages in  Oracle.
I never worked with oracle, and i know only basic staff like insert,update table, but now i need to call "vb_new_serial " function to get back from it integer here this function `function vb_new_serial return integer;`

This function is located in  Packages **VN_PKG** -> **vb_new_serial**

Here my code that i tried after i did some reasearches:

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(strConn2))
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "vb_new_serial";          

        conn.Open();
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dr.ToString());
        }
     }
}
```

Here the image

[image]

But here i did't get back nothing.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any parameters need to add in oracle command ? because return value is the first parameter added to the oracle command.

Like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Int16,
        ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
```

Comment: can you please add the full example i can't find the way to get integer from this function.

Comment: any function on oracle should have return type.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_details_func
    RETURN number;
 IS 
   emp_contact number; 
 BEGIN 
 SELECT ContactNumber INTO emp_contact
 FROM emp_tbl WHERE empID = '1';
 RETURN emp_contact;
 END;

Comment: I have got you in wrong direction, the function is working and it have return type (integer),i have problem to call to this function from c#, i never worked with oracle before.(function wroted by another developer it's working 100%)I added image of oracle tree

Comment: change the function then or told your another developer to change the function in procedure if you don't want to return anything.

Comment: begin
  -- Call the function
  :result := vbank_pkg.vb_new_serial;
end; this is function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61488/discussion-between-vova-potapov-and-v2solutions-ms-team).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your code in order to get the integer that the Oracle function returns:

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(strConn2))
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "VN_PKG.vb_new_serial";        

        OracleParameter myReturn = new OracleParameter("myReturn", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue); 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(myReturn);

        conn.Open();    
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show(myReturn.Value.ToString());
     }
}
```